# Finding the integral curves of $V=(y-z)\partial_x+(z-x)\partial_y+(x-y)\partial_z$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, vector-analysis

I want to find the integral curves of $V=(y-z)\partial_x+(z-x)\partial_y+(x-y)\partial_z$.

I have solved the system 
$$\dot{\gamma}=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&-1\\-1&0&1\\1&-1&0\end{pmatrix}\gamma$$
The eigenvalues of the matrix are $0,\pm i\sqrt{3}$, so I obtained
$$\gamma(t)=a+b\cos(\sqrt{3}t)+c\sin(\sqrt{3}t)$$
where $a,b,c\in\mathbb{C}^3$.

But we require the image of $\gamma$ to be in $\mathbb{R}^3$. So can I simply restrict $a,b,c$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$? Or is a different approach needed?

Answer (score 1):

Given

$$
M =\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 1 & -1 \\
 -1 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & -1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

the system

$$
\dot\gamma = M\cdot\gamma
$$

is equivalent to

$$
\dot\gamma = \vec\omega\times\gamma
$$

where $\vec\omega = -(1,1,1)$

then

$$
\vec\omega\cdot\dot\gamma =\vec \omega\cdot(\vec\omega\times\gamma) = 0
$$

and after integration  follows

$$
\vec\omega\cdot\gamma = C_0\Rightarrow \vec\omega\cdot(\gamma-\gamma_0) = 0
$$

which means that $\gamma$ evolves onto a fixed plane with normal $\vec\omega$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By orthogonality of sine and cosine, there is no linear addition of 1, sine and cosine that would cancel out the imaginary part. Therefore, since gamma is a pure real, then a, b and c are pure reals.